# Linear Algebra books that also covers multilinear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation, multilinear-algebra

I want self-studying linear algebra but I also want to know what tensors are. I don't see any books that cover both linear and multilinear algebra (tensors are part of multilinear algebra right?). So if there are any books that do would be great. I don't mind that the books being "theoretical" i.e.,proof-theorem style books without many(or any) application since I want to really develop my intuition behind the subject.

Comment: Before giving any book recommendations, what do you want tensors for (i.e. what do you want to go on and look at with tensor knowledge?) There are *vastly* different treatments (night and day differences) depending on what your goal is.

Comment: If you put it like that, I guess I leaned more towards rigorous treatment of tensors. Got some basic knowledge about proofs since I also reading through Abbott Understanding Analysis right now.

Comment: I understand how you're trying to anticipate what I may be asking, but it doesn't answer my question. Different treatments of tensors are not necessarily less rigorous than one another, but they definitely come in different flavors and an active learning goal (again, what do you want tensors for to continue studying) would be best to know.

Comment: I want to study up on differential geometry as my end goal but for now, I just want a quick overview of how tensors work beforehand.

Comment: Generally speaking, I can think of four popular flavors of tensors. If you ask a mathematician for a rigorous treatment, you'll get some nonsense (kidding) about universal algebra and an introduction to commutative diagrams, which one uses to start understanding category theory. A very general notion of a multidimensional array that maps from products of spaces is useful in optimization and programming. However, for you I highly recommend a combination of the last two. Spend time learning about dual spaces (Axler is a good place to start) and then learn about tensor indices in SR from Carroll.

Comment: Because I ran out of comment room, the third flavor is what is focused on by engineers doing rigorous proofs (yes they exist - in fact the first time I was ever introduced to measure theory rigorously was in a mechanical engineering course). After you read Axler's section on dual spaces, I suggest reading [Papadopoulous's notes](https://csml.berkeley.edu/Notes/ME185.pdf) to get a good feel for tensor rigor and practice problems in Cartesian coordinates tensor calculus. The fourth flavor (the famous physicist "a tensor transforms like a tensor") from Carroll will solidify the concepts via SR.

Answer (score 1):

One book you could use would be *Lectures in Geometry, Semester 2: Linear Algebra and Differential Geometry*, by Postnikov. It's the second volume in his six-part series *Lectures in Geometry*.

This might not be a good book to learn linear algebra from by itself, as there are no exercises and some important topics are omitted. It's really focused on what's needed for differential geometry. But it could supplement another book well.